Dawson's Creek - Pacey bar fight
What season and episode of Dawson's Creek was it where Pacey locks up the restaurant and a group of guys surround an jump him? It has to do with him sleeping with the wife of one the men.

Chris, you can self-answer. :)

Hmm. It said I need more rep to answer my own question. Will try again, thank you.

It  was in Season 6: Episode 23
